# Tabrisjs Cannot establish connection package.json file

Tags: javascript, native, tabris

I followed the tabrisjs tutorial instructions to the letter when I get to this part

> In the URL tab of the developer app, enter:
>
> > http://(development-machine-ip-address):8080/

I do as it instructs and I get the following error

> Could not establish connection
>
> > Could not open file: http://(ipaddress):8080/package.json

How do I go about figuring out why it cannot find the file?

I am on the same network as my development laptop with the android device , so that shouldn't be the problem.

here is the link:

https://tabrisjs.com/documentation/0.9/getting-started

Comment: Tutorial link please?

Comment: @gregnr sorry edited it in

Comment: Have you started the http-server inside the directory of the example? Can you open the package.json URL in you browser (just for testing)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open a browser on the device and point it to the package.json URL the developer client complains about (http://(ipaddress):8080/package.json). If the browser can open the file, but the developer client still complains, then this is a bug and should be reported in the [tabris.js issue tracker](https://github.com/eclipsesource/tabris-js/issues). If the browser cannot open this file, the problem is on the server side.

One common reason is that `http-server` has been started in another directory.

Another common problem is that there is already a server running on port 8080. In this case, `http-server` would open on the next available port, e.g. 8081.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I found that this was down to my firewall, AVG, blocking the connection attempt.  The solution

- From Menu->Settings->Components choose Firewall
- Choose Network profiles
- For your current network adaptor change the profile to private (you have to establish whether this is a safe thing to do)
- Back on the Policies page check *Allow all connections with friends in private mode*

With other firewall software you will have to find out just how you allow access to that port from other devices on the same network

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit old but, for anyone else who runs into the problem, I was able to fix it on Android M (S7Edge) by exiting the server (**CTRL+C**) then force stopping the developer app and removing all its data. After restarting the app and the server, everything worked fine.

I seemed to have caused the problem by trying to connect while the server was running in a directory which did not have a Tabris application. I accidentally miss-typed the directory name on the CD command and didn't notice until I started trying to figure out why it wasn't working.

After stopping the server and restarting it in the correct directory, the file could be opened from a web browser but the developer app still seemed to be using the old (incorrect) location. This issue persisted even after rebooting the computer.